# Using Google Chromium's Views Project as an Application Framework in C++

Tags: c++, frameworks, open-source, google-chrome, desktop-application

I have had contact with Google Chromium Code and that’s terrific for building applications with. The problem now lies that no-one has tried to use it outside Google Chromium Project. What I have in mind is to develop an open source project which may be used for this purpose. The fundamental goals would be:

- Guarantee Linux-Windows support for the same code.
- Take advantage of all resources available like thread control, stats, unit test…
- Make it clearer how to use Skia for graphic effects and customizations.
- Present a useful application doing the most of this.
- Integrate C++ and JavaScript code using V8
- Use Webkit for rendering html content

There’s a chance of it get off the paper. What do YOU think?

Claudio M. Souza Junior

Developer.

Comment: the gyp/ninja build system is superior in many ways to anything existing in the open source space, including cmake and scons. And damn easy to bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://github.com/lianliuwei/chromium_base

I create it for the same reason like you.

chromium is great project. It's code could be useful to using in other project. but It need time to extract it. I see one project to extract the ui part, but it change too many for noreason for example it change the .cc to .cpp. my project extract the base, ui, view part for the origin project, rm the ICU (it's so big) and gurl(you can add it quick) keep the gyp, gclient, grit-i18n, gtest, gmock... change the code little. and keep the extract history. I add a new type of messageloop for using it in the MFC(for company project :(   ) now it can only work on Windows but it's no so hard to make it work on linux.(google do it all)

for use the browser in you project you can see the http://code.google.com/p/chromium/ for help.

It's great this project help you a litte. I at first think it's a no one care project.

Comment: too bad it hasn't been updated in 2 years. And using the fetch/gclient is really painful

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have looked at the extensively documented and developed QtWebkit and know why you don't want to use that?

I'm sure it will be easier to use V8 in a QtWebkit application than to somehow tear out Chromium's "View project".

Qt has the bonus that as long as you operate within the framework, everything will work on *a lot* of different platforms (more than Chomium now supports I think).

Comment: Thank you, I have considered this option too, but I've posted it here in order to see how much interesting it could be, once chromium projects like base and V8 have a lot of powerful stuff. I already make use of it, but it'll require a mores thorough research in order to work properly.